# dynamic ip , want stable access route

Tags: dynamic-ip

i have a dynamic ip that changes every 30 days or so and i would like to make a server so that when i access a static address ( lets say : www.staticaddress.com ) it will direct me to my server even when my ip has changed. Note: my internet connection first enters a router that supplies 3-4 computers with internet connection ( via cable or wireless ) .  can anyone direct me to a tutorial?

Regards,

Alex Badescu

Comment: Voting to migrate on Serverfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a domain name whose DNS records you control fully, this can in fact be done.

- Sign up for a dynamic DNS provider like DynDNS
- Get a sub-domain under one of their domains like `xyz.homeip.com`
- In your domain's DNS records, for `www`, add a CNAME entry pointing to `xyz.homeip.com`

Comment: so ok, i've created an account on DynDNS and got my subdomain ( badescuga,dyndns.org ) , i've configured the details on my router (i've logged in my dynDNS account and domain, in my router menu on the tab" Dynamic DNS, succesfully ). Now what?

Comment: @Badescu your IP will now be reachable through `badescuga.dyndns.org`. If you want to map this to a domain like `www.staticaddress.com` you need to change that domain's DNS settings and add a CNAME.

Comment: ah ok. But when i try to connect to badescuga.dyndns.org it doesn't work. the thing may be because i am currently on my laptop which is connected through wireless to my router. Doesn't there have to be any settings applied so that when the request reaches the router, the router knows from which computer to grab the response?

Comment: @Badescu you will need to set up port forwarding (sometimes also called NAT) in the router for the ports you want to access on your laptop

Comment: that's what i did and that didn't work. http://img69.imageshack.us/img69/2108/52679383.png ; the 192.168.1.104 for the http is my associated addresss from the router. i have the apache server working ( when i run the http://localhost it displays my (local) home page )

Comment: @Badescu that looks okay... Check your local firewall on your machine whether it accepts incoming connections. If that doesn't work, it's maybe worth a separate question on serverfault.com